# Problema de autorização com o pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No controller `lodger` coloquei essa função `authorize`, passando usuário que está logando no sistema, dentro do metodo `#destroy`.

O que preciso é que apenas o usuário **admin** possa realizar a operação de deleção.

```
 def destroy
    authorize current_user

    @lodger.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to lodgers_url, notice: 'Lodger was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Dentro do arquivo `lodger_policy` que foi gerado pelo pundit eu coloquei o metodo `def destroy` para ele buscar **exatamente** nesse local e fazer a verificação se o usuário é **admin** ou **normal_user**

```
def destroy?
    current_user.admin?
end
```

conforme definido no model user com o enum abaixo

```
enum role: [:normal_user, :admin]
```

e no index da view lodger eu ainda verifico se o usuario que está logado é mesmo o admin, da seguinte forma:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
<li><%=current_user.admin?%></li>   ##isto é, aqui nessa linha ele retorna true se o usuário realmente for admin
<%= render 'admin_index' %>
<% else %>
<%= render 'normal_user_index' %>
<% end%>
```

mas o problema é que mesmo ele retornando true no inicio da index, confirmando que o usuário realmente é um admin ele **não** autoriza utilizar a função de deleção.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é a forma com que vc está tentando autorizar a ação.

Veja este exemplo de classe de autorização:

```
class PostPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :post

  def initialize(user, post)
    @user = user
    @post = post
  end

  def delete?
    user.admin?
  end
end
```

Para autorizar o delete, deveria ser chamado no controller:

```
def delete
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post
  ...
end
```

Repare que: O que deve ser passado para o autorize é o objeto que será verificado e não o usuário. O usuário é preenchido automaticamento pelo pundit, perceba também que deve ser usada a variável user que é como o usuário logado é passado para o pundit.